# ESP8266 D1 mini pro/ Arduino IOT, no function is getting called

Tags: arduino, esp8266, c++

I coded this:

```
    /*
  Sketch generated by the Arduino IoT Cloud Thing "Untitled"
  https://create.arduino.cc/cloud/things/4f3ba335-0e75-454b-913b-81b6af405e02

  Arduino IoT Cloud Variables description

  The following variables are automatically generated and updated when changes are made to the Thing

  int wateringTime;
  CloudSchedule wateringSchedule;
  bool wateringScheduleOn;
  bool waterOnOFF;

  Variables which are marked as READ/WRITE in the Cloud Thing will also have functions
  which are called when their values are changed from the Dashboard.
  These functions are generated with the Thing and added at the end of this sketch.
*/

#include "thingProperties.h"

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found

  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  /*
     The following function allows you to obtain more information
     related to the state of network and IoT Cloud connection and errors
     the higher number the more granular information you’ll get.
     The default is 0 (only errors).
     Maximum is 4
  */
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();

  /*set pin 16 output*/
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  
  
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // LED als Output definieren
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // Ausschalten
  Serial.print("SEtup");
}


void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  // Your code here*/
}

/*
  Since WateringSchedule is READ_WRITE variable, onWateringScheduleChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onWateringScheduleChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon WateringSchedule change
  Serial.print("onwateringschedulechange");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // Ausschalten
  delay(5000);
}
/*
  Since Water is READ_WRITE variable, onWaterChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onWaterChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon Water change
  Serial.print("onwaterchange");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // Ausschalten
  delay(5000);
}

  
/*
  Since WateringScheduleOn is READ_WRITE variable, onWateringScheduleOnChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onWateringScheduleOnChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon WateringScheduleOn change
  Serial.print("onWateringScheduleonchange");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // Ausschalten
  delay(5000);
}
/*
  Since WateringTime is READ_WRITE variable, onWateringTimeChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onWateringTimeChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon WateringTime change
  Serial.print("onWateringTimeChange");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // Ausschalten
  delay(5000);
  // Add your code here to act upon Water change
}

void watering()  {
  /*pin D0 on */
  digitalWrite(16, HIGH);
  /*delay(wateringTime * 1000)*/
  digitalWrite(16, LOW);
}



/*
  Since WaterOnOFF is READ_WRITE variable, onWaterOnOFFChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onWaterOnOFFChange()  {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // Ausschalten
  delay(5000);
  // Add your code here to act upon WaterOnOFF change
  
}
```

I also created a dashboard, with some buttons etc...
As soon as I start the script, the main-loop begins to run and the ESP connects to my wifi, but if I change a value with my phone, none of the functions is getting called.
I can see on a other dashboard, that those values are changing.[image: Arduino IOT variables]
I have already tried Serial.print(""); inside the functions, but it also wont work.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wrong stack exchange site.

Comment: the delay(5000) stops things happening for 5 seconds. Don't use a delay(),  use the system time to action events.

Comment: @Kartman thanks!
Is it okay to use delay(), if I wont other functions to be run at the same time?

Comment: no. Do not use delay().